# Is it possible to move the command prompt to a certain position on the screen?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd, move

As the title says, is it possible? I've searched all over the internet in order to find it, but whatever variation of my search query I come up with, I end up getting results which are about the move command which is used to move files/folders, instead of the actual prompt.

When doing

```
mode /?
```

The only result I can remotely relate to the appearance of the prompt is the Display mode,

`(mode con:cols=x lines=y)`

As I've said, I can't find any documentation about this & I'm extremely curious, can it be done? I know it can be done in Visual Studio to set a position where it should show it's dialog, so I'm presuming it can be done...

PS: If it can be done, what value should I use to have it perfectly centered when using these size settings?

```
mode con:cols=50 lines=15
```

Thank you in advance.

Yorrick

Comment: Your asking it to do in an already running command prompt? Because if you have *.lnk (shortcut) you can set the start position on the Layout tab of the properties window of the shortcut.

Comment: You can use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to do that.

Comment: I'm trying 2 learn .bat scripting here... I'm trying to do it with just coding instead of using properties & all that... Also, Wimmel, I don't see how that program is applicable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do so directly from a batch file. However, you can write a small program to do that. The relevant Windows API function is [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: So doing so with only using the batch script is impossible? I have no clue when it comes to C++ and so I'll probably just skip the centering the window part & just leave it as it is at the moment then. Thanks